# Extracting coefficients from g=a*x+b*y+c*x*y

Tags: equation-solving

I have a Response Surface Equation (RSE) that I'm trying to extract coefficients from. It has a form similar to:

```
g = a*x + b*y + c*x*y;
```

I want to be able to extract the coefficient from `x`, `y`, and `x*y`.

However, when I use

```
Coefficient[g, x, 1]
```

I get `(a + c y)`, which is not what I want (I want just `a`). Is there any way to extract `a`, `b`, and `c` directly?

Comment: It sounds like you want to find `Coefficient[g,x,1]` **and** `Coefficient[g,y,0]` which you could do (in this particular case) with `Coefficient[g, x, 1] /. y -> 0`

Comment: Coefficient[g /. y->0, x, 1]

Comment: Also, `{1, 0} /. CoefficientRules[g, {x, y}]` which is probably a bit more robust.

Comment: Hi! and welcome to Math.SE.  I've formatted your code, but please take the time to learn [how to format](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) your posts.  (For code, indent four spaces or back ticks.  There's also a code button, `{}`, above the edit window.)

Comment: @bobthechemist Why not to formulate your reply as an answer?

Comment: I'll just upvote @Mr.Wizard - he needs the rep ;-)

Comment: @bobthechemist LOL -- I'll gladly delete my answer if you wish to post your own.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard nah, I'm badge hunting not rep hunting, so I won't be bothered unless your answer gets 24 more upvotes

Comment: I went with @bobthechemist's solution. I need to figure out this "/." functionality. 2nd day using Mathematica.

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me that [`CoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoefficientRules.html) is appropriate:

```
g = a*x + b*y + c*x*y;

rules = CoefficientRules[g, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1} -> c, {1, 0} -> a, {0, 1} -> b}
> ```

You can extract whatever you wish from that rules list, e.g.:

```
{1, 0} /. rules
```

> ```
> a
> ```

And I just noticed that [bobthechemist](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7167/bobthechemist) already suggested all of this, so full credit to him.

---

Attempting to make this answer more my own here is a function that may automate your task.  *Now corrected thanks to [ubpdqn](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1997/ubpdqn).*

```
myCoefficientRules[poly_, vars_List] :=
  Times @@ (vars^#) -> #2 & @@@ CoefficientRules[poly, vars] // Sort
```

Result:

```
myCoefficientRules[g, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {x -> a, y -> b, x y -> c}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

A unsorted version similar to Mr. Wizard:

```
f[exp_, var_] := 
 CoefficientRules[exp, var] /. 
  Rule[List[a__], y_] :> Inner[Power, var, List[a], Times] -> y
```

Example:

```
f[a x^2 + b x z + c x y z , {x, y, z}]
```

yields:
{x^2 -> a, x y z -> c, x z -> b}

Comment: *Forehead slap*.  Why did I use `Pick` instead of `Power`?!  I *must* steal this as my answer is broken without it.  Big +1!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard very kind, thank you

Answer (score 2):

In fact bobthechemist has already given a good answer. However, just to give another view on it. This:

```
g = a*x + b*y + c*x*y + d*x^2*y + e*x^2*y^3;
lst = List @@ g

(*  {a x, b y, c x y, d x^2 y, e x^2 y^3}  *)
```

transforms the polynomial into a list. This:

```
    Select[lst, 
 MemberQ[#, y] && Not[MemberQ[#, x]] && Not[MemberQ[#, x^n_]] &]

(*   {b y}   *)
```

selects the term only with y. This

```
% /. y -> 1 // First

(*  b  *)
```

Returns the coefficient.